# Who is the guy in the opening movie of Dead Island?

Tags: dead-island

From whose perspective is the opening movie in Dead Island?

You meet the four playable characters through the course of the drunken shenanigans, so who is this guy?

Comment: It's easy to say it's a random guy but the point is, they do this to show the characters. BUT why do you wake up on the same bed that some random guy passed out on? This is why it makes you wonder who it is.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's conclusively any named character (future DLC notwithstanding).

You can see the person in the intro for a moment in the bathroom mirror, I've taken a few screenshots:

[image: intro guy in the mirror]

Considering that the characters seem to retain their clothes and general look from the intro, it doesn't appear to be Ryder White since Ryder's apparel has a button-down military style shirt and intro guy just has a tan collared shirt on. Example:

[image]

It's hard to tell from screenshots but their hairstyle and facial hair seem different as well, Ryder has very short hair and no facial hair while intro guy seems to have slightly longer hair and a goatee.

At this point intro guy seems to be a throwaway character to introduce everyone else. It's possible that he'll show up in DLC at a later time but the only DLC I've heard of is Ryder-centric.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I think it's [Ryder White](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Ryder_White%27s_Campaign).

Answer (score 2):

It is the player basically, they tried to make the opening homogenic. You kinda meet yourself in the opening and its all kind of weird and stuff... but on the other hand you were drunk. So who knows if you actually met yourself or you thought you met yourself.

The reason why it is you, is because basically you start the game in the same room where you passed out.

On the other hand if you look closely at the arm while you are drinking you can see Logan his hand... which doesn't make a lot of sense either since you met yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the same room. If you pay attention the room from the intro and the room you start in are different, so it may just be a random drunk dude to show you how the playable characters personalities are.